I don't Understand why reversing the process gives me different results. Largest palindrome product
This problem is from project Euler problem 4. I am a beginner in programming and I only understand data types, variables, loops ,arrays and functions. if the answer turns out to be really complicated please tell me what to look up.
So the problem was: A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2 -digit numbers is 9009=91*99.
Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.
The difficulty of this problem is apparently easy but It took me days. The original program I designed had some syntax errors so I used some help from chat-gpt.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

      // palindrome checker
bool is_palindrome(int p) {
    int original = p;
    int reversed = 0;
    int remainder;

      // Reverse the digits 
    while (p > 0) {
        remainder = p % 10;
        reversed = reversed * 10 + remainder;
        p = p / 10;
    }

    // Check if the original number is the same as the reversed number
    //turns out I don't have to say if original == reversed , return true.
    return original == reversed;
}

int main(void) {
    int largest_palindrome = 0;
    int factor1 = 0, factor2 = 0;

    // Check products of all pairs of 3-digit numbers
    for (int i = 10000; i <= 99999; i++) {
        for (int j = 10000; j <= 99999; j++) {
            int product = i * j;
            if (is_palindrome(product) && product > largest_palindrome) {
                largest_palindrome = product;
                factor1 = i;
              printf("Factor 1 : %d\n",i);//I wanted to see the patterns of the factors 
                factor2 = j;
              printf("Factor 2 : %d\n",j);
              
              printf(" product : %d\n",largest_palindrome);
            }
        }
    }

printf("The largest palindrome made from the product of two 5-digit numbers is %d (%d * %d).\n", largest_palindrome, factor1, factor2);
    
  return 0;
}*/

bool is_palindrome(int p) {
    int original = p;
    int reversed = 0;
    int remainder;

    while (p > 0) {
        remainder = p % 10;
        reversed = reversed * 10 + remainder;
        p = p / 10;
    }

    return original == reversed;
}

int main(void) {
    int largest_palindrome = 0;
    int factor1 = 0, factor2 = 0;

  //my genius idea
    for (int i = 99999; i >= 10000; i--) {
        for (int j =99999; j >= 10000; j--) {
            int product = i * j;

            // If the product is less than the largest palindrome yet, break loop
            if (product <= largest_palindrome) {
                break;
            }

            if (is_palindrome(product)) {
              
                factor1 = i;
              printf("Factor 1 : %d\n",i);
                factor2 = j;
              printf("Factor 2 : %d\n",j);
                largest_palindrome = product;
              printf(" product : %d\n",largest_palindrome);
              
            }
        }
    }

    printf("The largest palindrome made from the product of two 5-digit numbers is %d (%d * %d).\n", largest_palindrome, factor1, factor2);

    return 0;
}

1st program gave the right result for 3 digit numbers ,906609(993*991) which is. Took 45ms on an online compiler.
4 digit took 1 second or something like that. 99000099 (9999 * 9901).
For 5 digits it took a minute. 2147447412 (21516 * 99807) One factor seems to be a lot smaller than the other, I found that somewhat interesting.
9999999999 =9999800001. and 1000010000=100000000 so checking the factors from the upper limit and going i--,j-- should be a lot faster.
for the 2nd program the result is 2126776212 (21397 * 99396).took less than a second which is cool but the answer didn't match. After inspecting the printf's i saw that it was going in the right direction,2126776212 (21397 * 99396) is 3 palindromes behind  2147447412 (21516 * 99807) which is the result of the first one. for 3 and 4 digit pair of factors both programs give the same result.
Now I don't know if one of them is correct or both are wrong. I don't think i can look it up using some online calculator.
please tell me what you think. Thank you.

int i = 10000; i <= 99999 Those are 5-digit numbers, not 3-digit numbers.

And when you multiply 5-digit numbers, you get 10-digit numbers, which are likely to be too large for int, which is usually 32 bits

I should have made it clear from the start, I was able to do the 3 digit one ,I did some experimenting and 5 digit caused the confusion.

For 10digit numbers you need to use long instead of int, maybe even long long.

wait let me try

As others have pointed out, you're likely overflowing int with your 10-digit products, which is breaking your results. For both capacity and performance, all of your integral variables should be unsigned long.
Your approach in the second example is good, but there are also a couple of optimizations you can add to speed things up:
#include <stdio.h>

static int is_palindrome(unsigned long p)
{
    unsigned long reversed = 0;
    unsigned long original = p;
    while (p)
    {
        // (1)
        unsigned long remainder = p % 10;
        p /= 10;
        reversed = (reversed * 10) + remainder;
    }
    return original == reversed;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long largest_palindrome = 0;
    unsigned long factor1, factor2;
    for (unsigned long i = 99999; i >= 10000; --i)
    {
        // (2)
        for (unsigned long j = i; j >= 10000; --j)
        {
            unsigned long product = i * j;

            // If the product is less than the largest palindrome yet, break loop
            if (product <= largest_palindrome)
                break;
            if (is_palindrome(product))
            {
                largest_palindrome = product;
                factor1 = i;
                factor2 = j;
                printf("\t%lu\t%lu\t%lu\n", factor1, factor2, product);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("largest = %lu\n", largest_palindrome);
    return 0;
}


The change in is_palindrome makes the operation a bit faster because the CPU calculates the result and remainder of a division in a single instruction.

j never needs to be greater than i because that combination must have already been checked.



Add the condition if(i < factor2) break; after the inner loop for more optimization. ie for 6 digits, when you add this condition you significantly reduce the number of tests done by a factor of 10

Palindrome numbers with an even number of digits have the strange property of being all multiples of 11. So when i is divisible by 11 you'll need to check all possible values for j; but if i is not, then you want to check only for the possible values of j that are multiple of 11. With two six-digits factors this reduces the number of iterations from about 206 million to about 32 million (this results already include @Onyambu's optimization)

I have another question You said "For both capacity and performance, all of your integral variables should be unsigned long." why is that? cant I just write down the biggest data type for every program to ensure I never have that problem? like long long? Might be a dumb question.

Unless you need negative numbers, always use unsigned. CPUs do unsigned arithmetic, period. Signed integers are essentially syntactic sugar over unsigned integers, and the CPU has some built-in bit twiddling to support them, but all else being equal unsigned arithmetic is more efficient than signed arithmetic. On any modern 64-bit CPU long and long long are the same size, or you can just #include <stdint.h> and use type uint64_t (which is most likely typedef'd as unsigned long)

I see. Thank you
